# Rendering video on HTML5 CANVAS takes huge amount of CPU

Tags: html5-video, html5-canvas

I am using HTML5 Canvas for rendering video, but the rendering is taking huge amount of CPU? I am using GtkLauncher (with webkit 1.8.0) for rendering the video on the Canvas.
Can some one please throw some light on this? Is video rendering on Canvas not efficient for embedded systems? 
Also I would like to know, whether there is a way in HTML5 video tag to know the video frame rate, before I actually start to render the data on the Canvas. This I would need to know because I would have to set the timer (used for drawing the video frames) at that same frame rate .

Thanks and Regards,
Souvik

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the video rendering is not accelerated and needs to

- Decode on software
- Resize on software

You did not give system details so this is just a guess. By poking browser internals you can dig out the truth.

Video framerate cannot be known beforehand and in theory can vary within one source. However if you host file yourself you can pre-extract this information using tools like ffmpeg and transfer the number in side-band (e.g. using AJAX / JSON).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I also thought of the same. May be if I get this rendering and decoding hardware accelerated through the browser, I would get a better performance. Coming to the framerate part, actually I am developing an HTML5 Media player App for embedded gadget.The user may plugin a USB device which may have VFR video and the HTML5 player should be be able to play it. I guess, from your comment, using the video tag directly instead of the CANVAS may solve the issue. In that case the browser would handle framerate internally. Am I right?

Comment: Use <video> and you have less headache (and probably still now hw acceleration)